# Dynamically change directory in R

Tags: r, directory

I am newbie to R programming, and I wonder if I can change the current directory dynamically like so

```
setwd(paste(getwd(), "Directory_Path_Goes_Here", sep="/"))
```

or store the directory path in a variable and retrieve it into `setwd()`

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: It gives me an error **cannot change working directory**

Comment: The path must be incorrect / non-existent.

Comment: You could use file.path instead of paste.

Comment: Yes, You are right; I found that their is a duplicate path.

Comment: You should always create a project that has its own directory and work from that directory while accesing all you need from the other locations. The idea of `setwd()` and `getwd()` is very very bad!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code hope this will solve your problem.

```
 path <- getwd()
 setwd(paste0(path)
```